# What does Black Marketeer do?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

Ok, so [the feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/black-marketeer) gives you a resource pool which is apparently worth a certain amount of money.  You can also contribute non-monetary things to said pool.  Does said pool refresh?  How often does it refresh?  Is it actually 100 gp in coinage?  Is it 100 gp in goods?  Do you get them back when you use the goods?  How does this even work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one of those ways in which the SRD material is not a replacement for the original books, because the Product Identity material is vital to its function.

The full feat text (*Osirion: Land of Pharoahs*, p. 28) includes a sentence saying it functions the same as, and refers you to, the **Profits of Kalistrade** feat (which is *completely* PI) on page 73 of the *Pathfinder Chronicles Campaign Setting*. There it gives a complete description of how the feat(s) work: how you take gear or wealth out of it, how you restore it, and how it increases as you level.

Comment: Awesome, now I know what book to look through. Thanks for not giving a PI-infringing answer :)

Comment: You can find both feats texts over at the Archives of Nethys: [Black Marketeer](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Black%20Marketeer) and [Profits of Kalistrade](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Profits%20of%20Kalistrade)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz That stuff is unfortunately (and despite the site's predictable protestations) a copyright violation.

Comment: Pretty sure they operate under Paizo's community use policy as non-commercial. They certainly make no effort to hide; every update is posted directly to Paizo's own forums, which are very actively moderated.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz The CUP doesn't authorise republishing of material prohibited under the OGL though, it just allows nominative use of PI terms (and some other permissions that aren't relevant to this), such as would occur in a campaign blog that mentions places and people covered by PI, or like I did above (though I don't need the CUP to do so in this case). They're just in flagrant violation of the two licenses they "operate" under and copyright law. Whether Paizo cares/enforces on them doesn't alter our obligations here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Indeed; and even if Nethys is fully compliant, the terms of SE's license means that we wouldn't be. Which is why I simply provided a link. :)